# java.io.IOException: Illegal footer when importing certificate using keytool

Tags: java, glassfish, ssl-certificate, keytool

When I try to import my certificate to key store using `keytool` it shows me:

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.io.IOException: Illegal footer: ----END CERTIFICATE-----
java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.io.IOException: Illegal footer: ----END CERTIFICATE-----
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificates(X509Factory.java:337)
        at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificates(CertificateFactory.java:462)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.installReply(KeyTool.java:2571)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:998)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Illegal footer: ----END CERTIFICATE-----
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.checkHeaderFooter(X509Factory.java:590)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.readOneBlock(X509Factory.java:575)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.parseX509orPKCS7Cert(X509Factory.java:413)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificates(X509Factory.java:335)
        ... 5 more
```

I have successfully added CA certificate to my key store without any problem. Can anyone help? Is there any syntax error? I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -----END CERTIFICATE----- instead of ----END CERTIFICATE-----

Java 7 requies the 5 leading -, java 6 likely did not. See source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/provider/X509Factory.java

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the line break characters. Check if line feeds (LF) are required instead of carriage return (CR) or vice versa.

I had to convert CR to LF:
`sed -e 's|^M|\n|g' test_cr.pem > test_lf.pem`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found out that I have a new line character at the beginning and end of the certificate file causing the issue.